# Backbutton press navigates to two page backward in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone app sometimes it takes me two page backward although I pressed hardware back button just once. 
To handle the back button I used following code snippet:

```
 private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Handled = true;
     if (Frame.CanGoBack)
     Frame.GoBack();
 }
```

And in `OnNavigatedTo()` method I added following line:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

How can I make sure that one back button press will take just one page backward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line into the `OnNavigatedFrom` method:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

In case the `OnNavifatedFrom` doesn't exist in your partial class of the XAML page, create it like bellow:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
}
```